# After changing a property from a string to an object, elasticsearch can no longer index the data object

Tags: angular, elasticsearch, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, isodate

I've got some objects in a Firebase database which I'm using along with ElasticSearch to perform advanced queries.

However, when I had to change a property in one of those objects from a string, `organizer: "some name"` to `organizer: {id: "someId", name: "some name"}`, ElasticSearch can no longer index the object, saying:

```
[mapper_parsing_exception] failed to parse [organizer] Can't get text on a START_OBJECT
```

The data objects which remain as `organizer: ""` gets indexed properly, but the new structured objects does not. I don't understand why this is happening since I don't provide a custom mapping of these objects (I'm using [Firebase Flashlight](https://github.com/firebase/flashlight) to make it easier).

Can someone with more knowledge let me know how I can resolve this issue? It's causing big problems since I can't search for those objects anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you indexed `organizer: "some name"` the first time, a new field of type `string` (or `text`) has been created.

Now you try to index `organizer: {id: "someId", name: "some name"}` which is not a string anymore but an `object`, so that won't work.

You need to delete your index and properly reindex your data.

Comment: How can I delete the index?

Comment: With `DELETE index`